# How can I prevent django test from running examples in docstrings?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, testing, docstring

In my code I have:

```
def fn1():
    """
    fn1 description

    Parameters
    ----------
    components_list : list
        List of IDs of the reference groups

    Return
    ------
    ret : str
        A string representing the aggregate expression (See example)

    Example
    -------
    >>> reference_groups = [1,2,3,4]
    >>> expression = suite.getComponentsExpression(reference_groups)
        (tier1 and tier2) or (my_group)
    """ 
    #some code here
```

When I run: `./manage.py test`, it tries to run the example. Is there a way to prevent this from happening? e.g. maybe CLI option to skip docstrings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django 1.6 introduced a new test runner, which does not run doctests. So one answer to prevent tests is to upgrade Django!

If that's not possible, the proper fix would be to subclass `DjangoTestSuiteRunner`, disable the doc test loading, and tell Django to use your new test runner with the [`TEST_RUNNER`] setting.

Or if that's too tricky, a quick hack would be to change your docstrings so that they don't look like doctests, e.g.

```
>.> reference_groups = [1,2,3,4]
```